# How to create functions to manipulate objects inside objects with protected or private atributes?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn about classes/inheritance(in general), so I'm trying to make a game as a semester final project.

Lets say I have a class **SOLDIER** with an object of a class **INVENTORY** with an object of a class **POTION** (with size and amount).

If I want to make a function use_potion(), how do I do that? I could have everything public to make something like "soldier1.addlife(soldier1->inventory1->potion1->size), but that looks like a terrible practice. How do I do implement that with private/protected atributes?

*The potion is only 1 of the functions I will need to make with the same structure - *object->object->object->something* -, so I really need some help and examples to understand how to make them.

Comment: This would depend a lot on how everything else it set up. Simply though, each class would need to expose public methods to be used, and those public methods would manipulate the private data as needed.

Comment: It depends a lot upon your implementation, but still it is generally recommended to put variables at private scope, and create public member functions, i.e. only member function would be able to access/modify them, to prevent explicitly changing their values from outside. Functions could also be private, which in turn could only be accessible by other functions inside the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a public function in your SOLDIER class that invoke public function in INVENTORY object that invoke public function in POTION obj.

Here is an example structure of your program:

```
class SOLDIER 
{
private:
    class INVENTORY 
    {
    private:
        class POTION 
        {
            int size = 5;
        public:
            void use_potion()
            {
                size++;
                printf("use_potion in POTION obj");
            }
        };
        POTION pot;
    public:
        void use_potion()
        {
            pot.use_potion();
        }
    };
    INVENTORY inv;
public:
    void use_potion()
    {
        inv.use_potion();
    }
};

int main()
{
    SOLDIER s;
    s.use_potion();

    return 0;
}
```